# Changing the android titlebars which shows network bars, battery life and other things

Tags: android, qt, colors, qml, android-titlebar

[image: image 1]`how can i make the color of the  titleBar which displays network, battery life level and many other things on android to have the same color as the menuBar or ToolBar

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12



ApplicationWindow {

    id:root
    visible: true
    width: 350
    height: 550
    color: toolbar.color
   

    header: ToolBar {
        id: toolbar
        background: Rectangle {
        id: bakcground
        color: "lightCyan"
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window` property to access the window object, and then call the `setStatusBarColor()` method on it.

```
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorName)
```